# Change div side relative

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div floated to the right with width: 15%

And I have another div the float to it

Now the first div height is: `1246px`
and the second div height is: `9847px`

And I want that the right div will continue along the second div

the right div code:

```
 <div id="aside">
```

The second div code:

```
 <div id="art">
```

Now I write this code after the second div end:

```
document.getElementById("aside").style.minHeight = document.getElementById("art").clientHeight + "px";
```

And the result is that the right div get height of: `8927px`

But the second div have height of: `9847px`

I dont know why its happen, When I run this code:

```
document.getElementById("art").clientHeight
```

in the console, I get: `9847px`

I thought because I have images on the second div and they not loaded yet, the height is lower than it suppose to be when the code run

So I try to do:

```
window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementById("aside").style.minHeight = document.getElementById("art").clientHeight + "px";
}
```

But nothing happed,
What's the problem?
Pure js please

Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u6h6kmze/

Make shure you expand the output to see result

Comment: can u share your codes on jsfiddle?

Comment: @KamuranSönecek I edit and ad jsfiddle, look at the end of my message

Comment: when I set  ```overflow:hidden``` for #aside and #art, they get same height .

Answer (score 0):

I Think your problem with css.

Set your divs' overflow property as hidden

```
#art, #aside {overflow:hidden}
```